# Make an h1, Open more text information underneath

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make an header that acts like a button or something like this, that onclick will open underneath a text for example:

```
<h1>Dinosaurs</h1>
<p> Dinosaurs are ancient creatures....</p>
```

so if i click on my h1, it will do like an onclick event and behave like button, and open/close a paragraph text underneath

Comment: Don’t use an h1. Use a button instead. And style it appropriately

Comment: Hope this answers your question https://jsfiddle.net/xg3u4c65/18/.

Comment: Keep in mind a page should only have **one** `<h1`> element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think you would get an error: Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context as strictly only phrasing, not flow, content is allowed inside a button. See e.g.[link] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @AHaworth I’m not sure how you got that from my comment?

Comment: @evolutionxbox whoops, you are right as the following element is a p, for some reason I’d thought a div was being used, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, HTML has the `<details>` element, which you can style to your likings using the proper CSS.

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    Dinosaurs
  </summary>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut eum perferendis eius. Adipisci velit et similique earum quas illo odio rerum optio, quis, expedita assumenda enim dicta aliquam porro maxime minima sed a ullam, aspernatur corporis.
  </p>
</details>
```

More information here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details and here
https://markodenic.com/html-tips/